# html textarea input not inheriting the font family

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts

i am facing font type issue in text area, text area font is not inheriting the font which i have defined in my body. textarea is displaying different font text and make the screen looks odd

```
body {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}
```

[image: font family is different]

i have tried adding below css

```
textarea {
   font-family: inherit;
   font-size: inherit;

}
```

but doesnt work for me. even inline style doesnt worked.

Comment: No, its not duplicate, OP has already used solution mentioned there.
@pappu_kutty have you tried directly adding font-family for textarea instead of inherit?

Comment: @Gaurav it is a duplicate - BoltClocks' answer in the other question is the solution.

Comment: Put it in your css: textarea { font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif; }

Comment: This is an example of working code try this....(note i commented out the textarea styling !!!) 
<htlm>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif!IMPORTANT;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}
*/textarea {
   font-family: inherit;
/*   font-size: inherit;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>
Text that sits here and is not changed!!
</p>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
Some text here to fill the space and show it works!!!
</textarea>
</body>


</html>

Comment: i have added this body,button,input,select,textarea {
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
} and it worked